# Jena set level to all logging within

Tags: log4j, jena

the logging system in Jena is a bit complicated. Can someone give me a minimal example of how to set the logging level for **ALL OF** Jena? It seems there are many submodules that have its own logging configurations - what I want is a way to set it all at once. So that when I call various Jena methods from its different submodules in my own project - none of the logs would appear (i have described the case for setting it to OFF, for example).

I have tried setting levels for individual submodules but there are still some pesky logs appearing that I cannot seem to get rid of.

Comment: Jena uses slf4j for logging; Fuseki chooses to provide Apache Log4j2 to supply the logging implementation. So for an app using Jena as a library it is whatever your app uses.See the documentation for the app's choice of logging to control the logging output, such as setting the "org.apache.jena" which is the root of the logging hierarchy. It is useful to print the whole class, not the short name, to see which logger is causing output.